# VB.NET and MD5 for testing perfouse

Tags: vb.net, md5

I want to get MD5 value of a string. Searched and found an answer in stackoverflow.

Code:

```
Private Function GenerateHash(ByVal SourceText As String) As String
    Dim Ue As New UnicodeEncoding()
    Dim ByteSourceText() As Byte = Ue.GetBytes(SourceText)
    Dim Md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim ByteHash() As Byte = Md5.ComputeHash(ByteSourceText)
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ByteHash)
End Function
```

But I need plain MD5, not base64 encoded. **Return Convert.ToString(ByteHash)** didn't help me. So need your instruction.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "plain" MD5 - do you want a byte array? a hex string representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All u need was to covert the `Byte[]` to `String` Instead of `Base64` encoded string

```
Return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteHash)
```

Fixed Function :

```
Private Function GenerateHash(ByVal SourceText As String) As String
    Dim Ue As New UnicodeEncoding()
    Dim ByteSourceText() As Byte = Ue.GetBytes(SourceText)
    Dim Md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim ByteHash() As Byte = Md5.ComputeHash(ByteSourceText)
    Return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteHash)
End Function
```

Comment: I got a great solution [here] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Thanks BTW.